# If else statement returning only the first return

Tags: javascript

on codewars I am doing the problem 'Century from the year' in javascript. I'm sure my solution is not the most efficient or even close but I do believe it should work. Before I unlock the solutions I would like to figure out why this long method of doing it is not working. I keep changing it around but cannot figure out why every century just returns 1.

the output should be:

centuryFromYear(1705)  returns (18)
centuryFromYear(1900)  returns (19)
centuryFromYear(1601)  returns (17)
centuryFromYear(2000)  returns (20)

my output is:

Testing for year 1705 - Expected: 18, instead got: 1
Testing for year 1900 - Expected: 19, instead got: 1
Testing for year 1601 - Expected: 17, instead got: 1
Testing for year 2000 - Expected: 20, instead got: 1
Test Passed: Value == 1

Here is my code:

```
function century(year) {
    if (year >= 1 || year <= 101) {
    return 1
    } else if (year >= 101 && year < 201) {
    return 2
    } else if (year >= 201 && year < 301) {
    return 3
    } else if (year >= 301 && year < 401) {
    return 4
    } else if (year >= 401 && year < 501) {
    return 5
    } else if (year >= 501 && year < 601) {
    return 6
    } else if (year >= 601 && year < 701) {
    return 7
    } else if (year >= 701 && year < 801) {
    return 8
    } else if (year >= 801 && year < 901) {
    return 9
    } else if (year >= 901 && year < 1001) {
    return 10
    } else if (year >= 1001 && year < 1101) {
    return 11
    } else if (year >= 1101 && year < 1201) {
    return 12
    } else if (year >= 1201 && year < 1301) {
    return 13
    } else if (year >= 1301 && year < 1401) {
    return 14
    } else if (year >= 1401 && year < 1501) {
    return 15
    } else if (year >= 1501 && year < 1601) {
    return 16
    } else if (year >= 1601 && year < 1701) {
    return 17
    } else if (year >= 1701 && year < 1801) {
    return 18
    } else if (year >= 1801 && year < 1901) {
    return 19
    } else if (year >= 1901 && year < 2001) {
    return 20
    }

};
```

Comment: For every one of those test inputs, `year >= 1` is true so the first condition is true.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (year >= 1 || year <= 101)
```

If year is greater than or equal to 1, return 1.

Comment: Yeah I meant to put ```if (year >= 1 && year <= 101) ``` thank you!